# design architecture: GUI Control DatabaseWrapper Database

Tags: oop, architecture

Say that I have a program with the following architecture:

**GUI:** The graphic user interface which let the user interact with the program

**Control**: the "logic" of the program and the middle man between the GUI layer and the wrapper-layer.

**DatabaseWrapper**: The layer which handles connections to the database and retrieves data as result sets which are then returned to the Control layer as data structures that are not specifically related to databases, such as arrays and Strings.

**Database**: The database outside the program.

Does this particular architecture has a name? I presume it is MVC (Model–View–Controller) where Model is Database, View is GUI and Controller is Control? However, this either leaves out the Database or else 'model' of MVC is in this case simply composed of both Database and DatabaseWrapper? So maybe there is another more adequate name for the above architecture? Any help much appreciated. It is for a school project.

Comment: It is a somewhat layered architecture, but not MVC. It can be helpful for you to take a closer look at MVC and MVP, and depending on whether you have a use case for that, MVVM (which is the most developed in my opinion). What makes your question hard to understand is the `control` part. Please write what you understand behind those names you dropped.

Comment: @Mare Infinitus. Thanks! I've edited my question accordingly, let me know if you would like further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a form of a three tier layered architecture where you separated the data access layer (Database Wrapper) from the data store (database).

Check this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648105.aspx) from msdn or the obligatory [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-tier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture). Look at this image from another [article](http://dotnetpeoples.blogspot.de/2011/04/three-tier-architecture-in-aspnet.html):
[image: 4 layers]